# How change to AdHoc distribution to AppStore on the new Apple Developer site?

Tags: ios, app-store, provisioning-profile

First of all, I'm so sorry if my english is not good enough.

I change a provisioning certificate from AppStore to AdHoc because we had to test the push notifications on testflight. It was before Apple update the Developer Center.

Now I we are going to publish the app on the AppStore, but I can't change the distribution parameter of the certificate. Is there any way to do this or I should create a new one certificate?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Now, change again the certificate to form AdHoc to APP store and make new build and then upload it on the Itunes.

**Note:-Please refresh the profiles before making the new build after change it from the AdHoc to AppStore**

Comment: On the new redesign portal I'm not able to change it.

Answer (score 0):

I done some search on it and find this solution.check it works

**http://samwize.com/2012/11/14/ios-adhoc-distribution-with-the-new-xcode/**

You can check this link also:-

**http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/YourFirstAppStoreSubmission/TestYourApponManyDevicesandiOSVersions/TestYourApponManyDevicesandiOSVersions.html**